# Is there a way to (re)generate a keychain password so that it contains two numbers?

Tags: security, password, keychain

I am creating an account that requires a password with at least two numbers. I would like to use Apple suggestions of keychain strong passwords but it is generating only passwords with one number.

Is there a way to regenerate the strong password suggestions to contain at least two numbers?

Comment: What’s stopping you from storing the generated password and then editing it before assigning it?

Comment: When I edit the generated password, can I get it using the keychain tool? Or I have to remember it in the usual way?

Comment: @zdm when you submit the form, it will be auto-remembered for most sites